# Can I run ARCore Preview 1 App on Preview 2 release?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I've built an app which runs on ARCOre preview 1 package on Unity. I know Google has made major changes in preview 2.
My question is what changes will I have to make in order to run my ARCore preview 1 app run on preview 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the code in the Preview 2 sample app(s) and update your code accordingly. For example, here is the new code for properly instantiating an object into the AR scene:

```
if (Session.Raycast(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, raycastFilter, out hit))
            {
                var andyObject = Instantiate(AndyAndroidPrefab, hit.Pose.position,
                    hit.Pose.rotation);

                // Create an anchor to allow ARCore to track the hitpoint 
                // as understanding of the physical world evolves.
                var anchor = hit.Trackable.CreateAnchor(hit.Pose);

                // Andy should look at the camera but still be flush with the plane.
                andyObject.transform.LookAt(FirstPersonCamera.transform);
                andyObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f,
                    andyObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y,
                       andyObject.transform.rotation.z);

                // Make Andy model a child of the anchor.
                andyObject.transform.parent = anchor.transform;
             }
```

Comment: I am getting 3 errors right now and don't know how to solve them: 1. Assets/GoogleARCore/SDK/Scripts/Managers/RaycastManager.cs(45,38): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `TrackableHitFlag' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: 2. Cannot open file 'Packages/com.unity.analytics@2.0.13/UnityEngine.Analytics.dll.meta' for write.

Comment: 3. Failed to write meta file 'Packages/com.unity.analytics@2.0.13/Editor/UnityEditor.Analytics.dll.meta'

Comment: Make sure you delete all arcore sdk files/folders before importing preview 2. `TrackableHitFlag` needs to be changed to `TrackableHitFlags`. I think you can ignore the analytics errors, if needed delete those meta files and they will be regenerated.

Comment: Now it turned out into 4 errors: 1. llNotFoundException: tango_client_api2
GoogleARCoreInternal.TangoClientApi.CallsToConnectWithoutMatchingDisconnect () (at Assets/GoogleARCore/SDK/Scripts/Api/TangoClientApi.cs:130)
GoogleARCore.SessionComponent+<_AttemptRecoverIfInvalidState>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at Assets/GoogleARCore/SDK/Scripts/SessionComponent.cs:306)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)

Comment: ArgumentException: You can only call GUI functions from inside OnGUI.
UnityEngine.GUIUtility.CheckOnGUI () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUIUtility.cs:285)
UnityEngine.GUI.get_skin () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUI.cs:43)
UnityEngine.GUILayout.Label (UnityEngine.Texture image, UnityEngine.GUILayoutOption[] options) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayout.cs:7)

Comment: What shall I do?

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head. You should try figuring this stuff out on your own, as that's how you'll learn the most. Are you sure you corrected all other errors properly? Did you read the updated arcore documentation? I'll try to take a look at a computer later if I have time.

Answer (score 0):

**Common**

Preview 1 use Tango Core service that can changed Ar-Core service in Preview 2.

Automatic Screen Rotation is Handled.

Some Classes are altered like some reason of following.

**For Users:**

Introduce AR Stickers

**For Developers:**

A new C API for use with the Android NDK that complements our existing Java, Unity, and Unreal SDKs;

Functionality that lets AR apps pause and resume AR sessions, for example to let a user return to an AR app after taking a phone call;

Improved accuracy and runtime efficiency across our anchor, plane finding, and point cloud APIs.

Comment: I want to export my preview 1 project to preview 2....what steps do I need to take???  I keep getting Overriding existing asset with new GUID package error and the app is not working on Unity or on phone!

Comment: Most of the Classes are changed including service so download the preview 2 sample and develop it

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my app from Preview 1 to Preview 2. And it's not a lot. It had minor API changes like the ones for hit flags, Pose.position etc. It would probably be stupid to post the change log here. I suggest that you can file the below steps:

1. Replace the old sdk with the new one in the Unity Project
2. Then, check for the error in your default editor, vs or vs code or mono
3. Just check for the relevant API's in the deveoper docs of AR.

It's not such a cumbersome job, it too me some 5-10 min to upgrade that's it.

Cheers!

Comment: I am new to unity and 'am not understanding the error. What does this mean? >>>>         Overriding existing asset with new GUID from package, this may break links within your project to package assets (Assets/GoogleARCore/SDK/Scripts/Managers/SessionManager.cs)